# Decorate (change name) of job in Jenkins queue

Tags: jenkins

Is there a way to change the name of a job in the Jenkins queue?
The reason I ask is that we have a parameter job called "deploy", and it is called by multiple upstream jobs.  Our build queue has like a dozen of these "deploy" jobs, but each one is unique based on its parameters.

We would like to see what something like this in the queue:
deploy:foo-project
deploy:bar-project
...
instead of just:
deploy
deploy
...

Is this possible?

Comment: If you hover over an entry in the queue, you'll see the parameters for the particular build. Is that good enough ?

Comment: If that's the only way, then I guess that's good enough.  Feel free to create an answer so I can vote it.  Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you hover over an entry in the queue, you'll see the parameters for the particular build.

You could also look at using the [Build Name Setter plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Build+Name+Setter+Plugin); the build parameters will be available as environment variables that you can use in the build name string, e.g. deploy:${PROJECT_NAME}

Comment: The Build Name Setter plugin is useful, but unfortunately it does not seem like it can change anything until the job gets scheduled onto an executor, which means while it's waiting in the queue, it can have a very nondescript name.